# How can I query multiple classes on Parse?

Tags: ios, database-design, parse-platform, database-schema

I have 3 similar classes on Parse where I want to save all the data onto 1 object in iOS. Example of my database:

```
Class: Cycling
objectID (string)
calories (double)
User (pointer:User)

Class: Swimming
objectID (string)
calories (double)
User (pointer:User)

Class: Steps
objectID (string)
calories (double)
User (pointer:User)
```

I want to save the data from the 3 classes if the objectID is the same. How can I accomplish this? It would've been easier if these 3 classes were just 1 but the previous developer designed it with 3 tables.

Comment: Simple answer you can't. You will have to use pointers or relations

Comment: Actually you can, if you use cloud code: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide , but this way you have to do some javascripting.

Comment: You could create a Background Job that takes all the information from the 3 classes and transposes it to a new class so it's all in one place.